# How to pass a number array within a query string in HttpClient?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

This is my array

```
[1,2,4,7]
```

How to pass this array within a query string in HttpClient without converting to a string?

I tried to use:

```
let page_id = [1,2,4,7];
let params = new HttpParams();
params = Params.append('pages[]', page_id);
this.http.get(url, { params: Params });
```

But it returns the output like this

```
pages:['1,2,4,7']
```

What I want is

```
pages:[1,2,4,7]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the way to do it is convert the array elements to string and then in the backend convert back this to array.

```
let page_id = [1,2,4,7];
let params = new HttpParams();
params = params.append('pages', page_id.join(','));
this.http.get(url, { params: params });
```